# Apache2.4 with ProxyPass Strips ExpressJS-set Headers

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I've got WAMP (3.1.0 i.e. Apache 2.4) setup on Windows Server 2012R2 with proxypass to ExpressJS/Node application. In my httpd.conf:

```
<Location "/someurl/">
ProxyPass "http://localhost:1337/"
ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:1337/"
</Location>
```

This works great - except it's **stripping some headers set by Express** before sending to the client - specifically problematic is the caching headers. Express is setup with different max age for different types of files and so I'd rather not set cache controls in Apache. How do I tell Apache to pass those headers from the proxy right through to the client?

Headers from Express (localhost:1337) include:

```
Accept-Ranges    bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers        X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Origin     *
Cache-Control       public, max-age=0
Connection      keep-alive
Date        Thu, 04 Jan 2018 19:14:45 GMT
ETag        W/"97af-160c2918661"
Last-Modified       Thu, 04 Jan 2018 19:06:45 GMT
X-NODE_ENV      production
X-Powered-By        Express
```

Headers from Apache (localhost/someurl/) include:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  295
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date    Thu, 04 Jan 2018 19:28:33 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Location    http://localhost/someurl/
Server  Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31
```